# Transform cube on to surface of sphere in openGL

Tags: opengl, geometry, rendering, transformation

I'm currently working on a game which renders a textured sphere (representing Earth) and cubes representing player models (which will be implemented later).

When a user clicks a point on the sphere, the cube is translated from the origin (0,0,0) (which is also the center of the sphere) to the point on the surface of the sphere.

The problem is that I want the cube to rotate so as to sit with it's base flat on the sphere's surface (as opposed to just translating the cube).

What the best way is to calculate the rotation matrices about each axis in order to achieve this effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same calculation as you'd perform to make a "lookat" matrix.

In this form, you would use the normalised point on the sphere as one axis (often used as the 'Z' axis), and then make the other two as perpendicular vectors to that. Typically to do that you choose some arbitrary 'up' axis, which needs to not be parallel to your first axis, and then use two cross-products. First you cross 'Z' and 'Up' to make an 'X' axis, and then you cross the 'X' and 'Z' axes to make a 'Y' axis.

The X, Y, and Z axes (normalised) form a rotation matrix which will orient the cube to the surface normal of the sphere. Then just translate it to the surface point.

The basic idea in GL is this:

```c
float x_axis[3];
float y_axis[3];
float z_axis[3]; // This is the point on sphere, normalised

x_axis = cross(z_axis, up);
normalise(x_axis);
y_axis = cross(z_axis, x_axis);

DrawSphere();

float mat[16] = {
    x_axis[0],x_axis[1],x_axis[2],0,
    y_axis[0],y_axis[1],y_axis[2],0,
    z_axis[0],z_axis[1],z_axis[2],0,
    (sphereRad + cubeSize) * z_axis[0], (sphereRad + cubeSize) * z_axis[1], (sphereRad + cubeSize) * z_axis[2], 1 };

glMultMatrixf(mat);

DrawCube();
```

Where `z_axis[]` is the normalised point on the sphere, `x_axis[]` is the normalised cross-product of that vector with the arbitrary 'up' vector, and `y_axis[]` is the normalised cross-product of the other two axes. `sphereRad` and `cubeSize` are the sizes of the sphere and cube - I'm assuming both shapes are centred on their local coordinate origin.

Comment: Thanks for the quick and detailed response!

I understand how you generate the X, Y and Z axes now but I'm not sure I understand how they form a rotation matrix? Do we need to calculate the angle from the original 'Up' vector to the new axis and then apply the same logic to calculate the other rotations, or is it a case of generating one matrix that does this for you?

Comment: Please could you give an quick example with a point on the surface as a vector and show how to derive the final rotation matrix?

Comment: @user2033614 You don't need to calculate any angles at all, just basic vector operations. I've added some pseudo-code.

Comment: Thank you so much! It is much clearer now (I would up-vote but you need 15 reputation apparently - I'm sure others will though!).

Comment: Ok, I now have it with the correct orientation on the sphere -- only trouble is that it renders the cube 'flattened' and I am not sure why.

Could it be something wrong in the rotation matrix?

Comment: I've uploaded a screenshot to illustrate what I mean here:

http://imgur.com/8REtW8m

Comment: Looks like your axes aren't right. Make sure they're all perpendicular and normalised. Check your up vector isn't parallel to the sphere normal you're using.