# transform cube to sphere in opengl

Tags: c++, opengl, geometry, normals

I am built some Cubes with the triangle approach (24 verticies per cube).

Now I want to transform this cube to a sphere (maybe, I only want to have round corners) (later, I want to animate this transformation).

How can I realize this? Can I use texture coordinates or normals to do this?
I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14654329/transform-cube-on-to-surface-of-sphere-in-opengl), but it doesn't help me.

Comment: do you want to have a inscribed or circumscribed to the cube ?

Comment: No, I only want to change the geometry

Comment: then it's pretty simple, you just "normalize" each points as a vector, not to a norm of 1 but to a norm of the expected radius

Comment: Normalize each of the 24 points?

Comment: @Guiroux what is to normalize? the geometric coordinates? My primitive cube has only 4 verts per face, so the sphere looks a little "edged"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this with simple OpenGL, you'll need to use a finer tessellate of the cube. Instead of drawing each face with only two triangles, you subdivide it into smaller pieces. The easiest tessellation is to split the faces into smaller squares, and drawing them with triangle strips.

If you split each edge into `n` pieces, you'll end up with `n x n` squares or `2 * n * n` triangles for each face.

You can then interpolate between cube and sphere in the vertex shader. You draw the original cube. The sphere coordinates are obtained by simply normalizing the cube coordinates.

In the vertex shader, with `InterpFract` being the fraction of interpolation (0 for drawing the cube, 1 for drawing a sphere), the code could look something like this:

```
uniform float InterpFract;
attribute vec3 CubeCoord;

void main() {
    vec3 sphereCoord = normalize(CubeCoord);
    gl_Position = vec4(mix(CubeCoord, sphereCoord, InterpFract), 1.0);
}
```

This is for a sphere of radius 1. If you need a different radius, you can multiply `sphereCoord` by the radius.

If you also need normals, it takes some more math. Interpolating the normal of the cube and the normal of the sphere the same way the positions are interpolated does **not** produce correct normals. The correct solution is to interpolate the gradient vectors, and then calculate the normal as the cross product of the interpolated gradient vectors.

With more advanced OpenGL, you could avoid feeding in more vertices, and perform the subdivision of the faces with a tessellation shader instead.

Answer (score 1):

You could just scale each points to the sphere

let's say that your points are x[i], then to bring a point to the sphere, you do

`x[i] = x[i] * radius / norm( x[i] )`

assuming that your cube is centered on 0

if you want to interpolate this, it seems simple

I don't say that it works, but it looks to me like it should work

Comment: thanks, I thought that this works with a high count of triangles per face. I'm only use 2 triangles per face to reduce the overhead. Is there another aproach?

Comment: For more triangles, I found an article on http://mathproofs.blogspot.com.au/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html

Comment: i don't see how it is "for more triangles", it just maps with certain properties, but both are mapping from 3D point to 3D point