# Transform a BoxGeometry into a Sphere

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

I have a Box with different textures in each face, I'm trying to create a quad sphere based on it, using the same box textures in the sphere. Currently I'm trying to transform the cube into a sphere following this post:
http://mathproofs.blogspot.com.br/2005/07/mapping-cube-to-sphere.html

I'm not very familiar with threejs(or 3d programming in general) so my first approach was to try to apply the suggested formula to the geometry vertices, changing its x, y and z, but it just decrease the size of the box

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(2, 2, 2);
// I'm omitting material/textures etc
var vertices = cube.geometry.vertices;
var sqrt = Math.sqrt;
cube.geometry.dynamic = true;    

for (var i = 0; i < vertices.length; i++) {
    var v = vertices[i];
    var dx = v.x * sqrt(1.0 - ((v.y * v.y) / 2.0) - ((v.z * v.z) / 2.0) + ((v.y * v.y * v.z * v.z) / 3.0));
    var dy = v.y * sqrt(1.0 - ((v.z * v.z) / 2.0) - ((v.x * v.x) / 2.0) + ((v.z * v.z * v.x * v.x) / 3.0));
    var dz = v.z * sqrt(1.0 - ((v.x * v.x) / 2.0) - ((v.y * v.y) / 2.0) + ((v.x * v.x * v.y * v.y) / 3.0));
    vertices[i].set(dx, dy, dz);
}
cube.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

Anyone knows how I could achieve this?

Comment: I don't know Three.js, but this shows how to do this with plain OpenGL: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28831424/transform-cube-to-sphere-in-opengl.

Comment: Сan you show your code?

Comment: I'll update the question with the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This example does what you're after:
http://threejs.org/examples/#canvas_geometry_panorama_fisheye

Here's the relevant code:

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 300, 300, 300, 7, 7, 7 )

for ( var i = 0, l = geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {

    var vertex = geometry.vertices[ i ];
    vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar( 550 );

}
```

Comment: By the way, the main issue in your code is that you're not adding subdivisions to your box.